# Input with bottom line bar not increasing div length

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm creating a input with a bottom line that is rounded, I want the main div to increase in size according to input length, setting a min and max length for it.

[image]

I don't want to take the full width, just to increase the bottom bar and the div according to a length, like min length of 100px and max of 300px

Input code:

```
import React, { memo, useState } from 'react'
import { CommonInputProps } from '../Input'
import { twMerge } from 'tailwind-merge'

export interface NoStyleProps
  extends Omit<CommonInputProps, 'form' | 'placeholder'> {
  mainDivClass?: string
}

const NoStyle = ({
  register,
  className,
  hasError,
  mainDivClass,
}: NoStyleProps) => {
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false)

  const handleFocus = () => {
    setIsFocused(true)
  }

  const handleBlur = () => {
    setIsFocused(false)
  }

  return (
    <div className={twMerge('relative w-auto', mainDivClass)}>
      <input
        type="text"
        className={twMerge(
          `outline-none bg-white text-center `,
          className,
        )}
        autoComplete="off"
        {...register}
        onFocus={handleFocus}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
      />
      {hasError && (
        <div className="absolute bottom-0 left-0 right-0 h-1 bg-error rounded-full"></div>
      )}
      {isFocused && !hasError && (
        <div className="absolute bottom-0 left-0 right-0 h-1 bg-primary rounded-full"></div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default memo(NoStyle)
```

Comment: Could you provide the css properties of `border-input-border`

Comment: border-input-border is just a black color for the border, in the case of the image it is primary, actually we would not need it seens there is no border

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for,

It sets the width of the input field and the border according to the value length's width

Javascript (Reactjs):

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
const [inputWidth, setInputWidth] = useState('auto');

const handleChange = (event) => {
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
    setInputWidth(`${event.target.scrollWidth}px`);
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (inputValue === '') {
        setInputWidth('10px')
    }
}, [inputValue])
```

JSX:

```
<div className="flex justify-start items-start w-screen h-screen p-10">
  <input
    type="text"
    value={inputValue}
    style={{ width: inputWidth }}
    onChange={handleChange}
    className="leading-none bg-gray-200 no-outline"
  />

  <div
    className="absolute flex justify-center items-center mt-6 h-1 bg-[red] rounded-full"
    style={{ width: inputWidth }}
  ></div>
</div>;
```

*NOTE: This uses Tailwind CSS, if css styles are not showing, convert it to CSS or use the TailwindCSS library*